# enter "finish" state when not calling finish() causing BadTokenException

Tags: android

I have a very weird behaviour, which I cant find its cause.
the last thing I do on onCreate() is to call a certain method.
in that method i use
**progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Registering with Moish'd! server", true, false);**.
on the first run i get BadTokenException: Unable to add window on the *progressDialog* line.
the second run it passes it.
I read in forums that if the activity is in the middle of "finish" process than it might cause such an excetion.
after a long debugging tests, i tried asking for isFinishing(). something odd accoured - before calling the method, **isFinishing() returns false**.in the first line of the method I ask again and now **isFinishing() returns true**. 
how can it be ?!?  in the last line before entering a method its not "finishing" and in the first line of the method its suddenly "finishing", when NOTHING is happening in between (certainly not calling finish()).  anyone ?!?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can popup a `ProgressDialog` in `onCreate` as the main window of your `Activity` has not yet been drawn.  <strike>Try moving the `ProgressDialog.show()` call to your `onResume` method.</strike>

**UPDATE**

Ok, perhaps you can try this then:

```
private static final int DIALOG_INIT = 0;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    showDialog(DIALOG_INIT);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_INIT:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ((ProgressDialog) dialog).setMessage("Registering with Moish'd! server");
        //other dialog setup
        break;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: The main window hasn't been drawn in onResume either.

Comment: well, i could move it to onResume - but it wont serve me as I want.

Comment: if that so - why does in the second initialization it works fine ? is there any explanation to the weird isFinishing() ? or maybe to suggest a solution I could show such a ProgressDialog during onCreate ?

Comment: I'm still learning myself so I could be very wrong, but I think that the first time `onCreate` runs there is no window for your `ProgressDialog` to be drawn in.  If you then press the "back" button, your app has not necessarily been destroyed by the OS, and the window may still exist but not be visible to the user.  When you then run the app again `onCreate` is called again, but the original window still exists, so the `ProgressDialog` can be drawn successfully.  I think.  Could be wrong though.

Comment: sounds interesting. but still, I can't find anything resolving that issue :( so frustrating

Comment: tried it just now. its still now working, assuming your previous explanation still valid in this case also (get the same error). trying to move the required logic to an asyncTask and showing the ProgressDialog there